# JPA map MySQL json type, got garbled string

Tags: java, mysql, json, jpa, unicode

I'm using AttributeConverter to convert MySQL JSON column to Object as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31547965/1633272

It works fine when storing data into MySQL, I can see the correct values in WorkBench.

But, when getting the column back to java application, one unicode char is mapped into 3 chars.

Here's an example, the JSON string **"中"** just has 1 unicode char wrapped by quotes. In Evaluation Expression window I can see it is mapped as

```
0 = '"' 34
1 = 'ä' 228
2 = '¸' 184
3 = '\u00AD' 173
4 = '"' 34
```

Libs I'm using:

```
'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39',
'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.0.RELEASE',
'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.6.Final',
```

Seems it is a known issue for MySQL:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80631

Comment: So you're getting UTF-8 out of the database? Where's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that one unicode char is mapped into 3 garbled chars. In my example the correct JSON string has 3 chars (including 2 quotes), but now it has 5 chars when getting from MySQL to Java.

Comment: No, it's not mapped into garbled chars. It's just UTF-8.

Comment: OK, so how can I get the JSON string back correctly like the other columns?

Comment: At this point you should clarify to yourself what character encodings are. It'll be very useful the next time you get "garbled" characters.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, it is UTF-8. Don't know why it isn't mapped correct back to Java. I have a workaround now, still don't know it is a environment issue or library issue.

Comment: Usually (well, always) the case is that one "side" is using a different encoding than the other. If regular text columns are returned correctly, then the problem could be with the object mapper.

Comment: It's not in ObjectMapper, the ObjectMapper is converting String to Object, but the String itself is already wrong.

Comment: Yes of course. But can you read unicode data out of a VARCHAR field properly? If not, then it's an easy issue. If yes, then it'll be harder to debug.

Comment: Yes, it shows correctly in WorkBench just like the other columns. It is mostly like JPA doesn't interpret the column as UTF-8. So now I have to re-interpret it myself.

Comment: And you have the settings correct like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163328/jpa-utf-8-characters-not-persisted)?

Comment: I assume if settings not correct, other utf-8 columns will be wrong. The situation here is all persistence & reading (except reading on JSON column) are correct. However it is worth to double check.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in mysql-connector-java:5.1.40

Answer (score 1):

Seems that JSON column should not be mapped as String.

It should be mapped as byte[], then converted to Object.

```
public class JsonAttributeConverter<T extends Object> implements AttributeConverter<T, byte[]> {
    private final static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public JsonAttributeConverter(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(attribute).getBytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(dbData, clazz);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Using code above, reading is OK, but when persisting, there is an exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.
```