# Database unable to store in html format

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm using `springmvc`, `hibernate` and `mysql`. Whenever I upload a file in my project the database doesn't save in HTML format, I want that user who uploads the file, the database should maintain the format. What should I do?

Uploading a method which controller calls during upload. Apart from code, any general idea would be appreciated.

```
private String getContentDescription(MultipartFile file, Long contentCategoryId) {
  StringBuffer contentDescription = new StringBuffer();
  ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
  InputStream input = null;
  try {
    input = file.getInputStream();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    this.parser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, new ParseContext());
    input.close();
  } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e) {
    LOGGER.debug("Unable to read uploaded document", e);
  }
  String returnString = "";
  if (null != textHandler) {
    if (contentCategoryId==3 && contentCategoryId==4) {
      String contentText = textHandler.toString();
      returnString = contentText.substring(0, Math.max(0, contentText.length()));
    } else {
      String contentText = textHandler.toString();
      returnString = contentText.substring(0, Math.min(1200, contentText.length()));
    }
  }
  return returnString;
}
```

Comment: How is the above code relevant to saving text in a DB?

Comment: Its just a method which controller calls during saving the data. It may not help  , but any suggestion or any idea would help me out. Sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: So did you check whether this method is corrupting your String?

Comment: If you want to save the file your receive exactly as you receive it, don't *parse* it into something else first. Just retrieve the bytes and save them. Or convert the bytes to text using the correct character set and save that text,

Comment: What is the purpose of `Math.max(0, contentText.length())`? When do you expect a `String` to return a `length()` value less than `0`? `contentText.substring(0, Math.max(0, contentText.length()))` is the same as `contentText.substring(0, contentText.length())` which is the same as `contentText`.

Comment: `contentCategoryId==3 && contentCategoryId==4` some Schrödinger int?

Comment: thanks for replying @Andreas math.max and contentCategoryId are  project requirement.For particular upload in some categories full content will be display and for some only specific content will be displayed. In mysql i am using meduim-text as type of it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat no it is not corrupting my string but it doesn't save in HTML format. it saves in string format with some symbols.

Comment: @RC. yes it takes long as type variable

Comment: still a Schrödinger number, usually a number can **not** be `==` to 3 **and** `==` to 4

Answer (score 1):

You are using Tika to parse the HTML.  BodyContentHandler will only return the HTML found within the  tags and not include anything else.  What you want to do is read the entire file. Try something like this:

```java
private String getContentDescription(MultipartFile file, Long contentCategoryId) {
    try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: one thing which i am not understanding is why the return value is null??

Comment: it isn't.  it is returning sb.toString();  If it gets an exception, it will return null.

Comment: !J?word/glossary/webSettings.xmlj0{at_0JHR(/\Gid$m5lz_im>Q42
mA
<E
py?=,  i tried to upload doc file which contains a table by excuting above code .. the above result is of how it saves in database.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be analysed from the Application endpoint.

1. The request that you are sending to services should be `UTF-8`.
2. The data should be handled as `UTF-8` until you persist the data to

   DB.
3. Check your connection string that support `Unicode` and
       `Character Encoding`

> property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
>   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogdatabase?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"

4. To save the data to the database the column should be capable of storing stat particular data.To Store the `UTF-8` data convert the Db column to `lob or blob`  type.

Use the blow reference to config the JPA for the same.
[JPA utf-8 characters not persisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163328/jpa-utf-8-characters-not-persisted)

Spring configurations [Spring MVC UTF-8 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding)

Spring multi part file upload : http://javainsimpleway.com/spring-mvc-file-upload-single-and-multiple-files-upload/