# Spring data's save method results losing some data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring boot + Spring Data JPA + PostgreSQL. I have simply class containing some strings.

for example:

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
}
```

I am creating new persons:

```
Person person = new Person(null, "Roman", "Brzęścikiewicz");
```

Which contains some polish symbols like "ę" and "ś". 
When i am saving this to database:

```
personRepository.save(person);
```

Then i am left with person saved in database, which received ID and name but not surname example:

```
id;name;surname
1;Roman;
```

But when i have surname without polish symbols then i got correct row in database:

```
id;name;surname
1;Roman;Brzescikiewicz
```

My application properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Adding 
?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
As suggested on some qestions on stackoverflow won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about your database and tables encoding scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Actually this was veryy stupid problem. I was using PhpPgAdmin to search in database and phppgadmin has bug not displaying polish symbols... in pgadmin4 it is displaying correctly, and if i access data via spring JPA in rest controller it is also working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The characteter encoding is wrong. UTF-8 != utf8

```
characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Add it to your jdbc URL

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/db?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

You can read an example of same situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163328/jpa-utf-8-characters-not-persisted)

Comment: Added it to ma jdbc url and tried:
characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.jpa.characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.jpa.hibernate.characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.characterEncoding=UTF-8
hibernate.characterEncoding=UTF-8
and still not working

Comment: could you check that your DB schema encoding its also UTF-8? you can connect with some DB client to your DB and check that property

Comment: server encoding is utf8, database encoding is UTF8 with collation en_US.utf8 and same character type, when i am inserting surname with polish symbols via SQL it works, but not with spring data

Comment: could you copy here the value of your spring.datasource.url property?