# Streaming Data using Spring Data JPA gives Encoding Error

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, utf-8, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

In my project, I fetched all data with Stream but encoding didn't work.

My code looks like:

Repository:

```
@QueryHints(value = {
    @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE),
    @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
    @QueryHint(name = HINT_READONLY, value = "true"),
})
Stream<Book> findAllBy();
```

Service:

```
try (var allBooks = bookRepository.findAllBy())
            {
                allBooks.forEach(book -> {
                    
                   logger.info("Coming book name={}", book.getName());

                    // we need to free the memory
                    entityManager.detach(book);
                });
            }
```

When I fetch it, book name look like: `????`, `en ???? ??`, `????? ????? ??` ...

Then I implement encoding on database url: [JPA utf-8 characters not persisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163328/jpa-utf-8-characters-not-persisted) But it didn't work also.

Is there any suggestion? How can I solve this encoding problem?

**Solved like:**

I gave environmental variable for file-encoding.

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using environmental variable:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -jar jar-path
```